# Calling a DLL from C# (VS2008)

Tags: c#, dll

I have a DLL (Test.dll) which contains some Excel Addin, i don't know which version this is build with (might be with VB6, but i am not sure).

When i tried referencing this DLL in the VS2008 i get the message

**A reference to the <*DLL Name*> could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accrssible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM Component.**

If anyone could please help me in this, it will be great.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Tushar

Comment: What are you trying to do with this Addin? In a .NET project you can directly reference .NET assemblies and COM components, so if your DLL is neither of these your first task would be to find out what technology it uses to expose functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me the DLL you're trying to load isn't a *managed* DLL, or one that the CLR can treat as managed.

One solution would be to use *managed C++* (C++/CLI) to build a wrapper around the DLL. Another is to use PInvoke which is explained [here](http://www.microsoft.com/indonesia/msdn/pinvoke.aspx) and there's a tool for it I came across [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2008/03/14/making-pinvoke-easy.aspx).

You can also look in this thread: [Unable to Use DLL of VB6 Into ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5208-11196-0.html?forumID=73&threadID=180858&messageID=1843371).

Hope one these work out for you,
Asaf

Comment: @Asaf:  thanks for sharing the views, however i am not clear on using the managed C++ wrapper, i might be stupid at asking this - How to create a C++/CLI wrapper which i can't even refer ???

Also how could i use PInvoke to that.

Request you to please clarify.

Comment: @tush1r: You can either use PInvoke (directly from C#) or create a C++/CLI wrapper. There's no use in doing both. I'll try and add more on how to create such a wrapper soon.

Comment: @tush1r: You can learn more about mixed mode c++ assemblies - native & managed c++ in the same assembly - here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k%28VS.80%29.aspx

With mixed mode you can use the native c++ to call DLLs and the managed to expose it to the .Net world.